# How can I handle click events on a Bootstrap table dropdown menu that controls column visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm currently building a table with [Bootstrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/). I'm also using the [showColumns](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#showcolumns) feature which enables a dropbox to choose which column to show.

Now I need to handle when the user clicks on one of the dropbox items with some custom commands.

I've already tried with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-item.dropdown-item-marker', function() {
        
        console.log("hello")
  });
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap-table API actually has an [event](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#oncolumnswitch) for this.

The relevant part of the doc is:

> **onColumnSwitch**

> **jQuery Event**: column-switch.bs.table
>
> **Parameter**: field, checked
>
> **Detail**:
>
> It fires when switch the column visible (showColumns). The parameters
> contain:
>
> field: the field name corresponding to the switch column. checked: the
> checked state of the column.

Assuming your table has an id `table` and you've set `var $table = $('#table')` then the following would work. I changed the "hello" in your question to output the event parameters just for the sake of the explanation.

```
$table.on('column-switch.bs.table', function(e, field, checked) {
    console.log(field, checked)
    })
```

Here is [an example](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/nickjrotundo/15480) using the bootstrap-table online editor, but with an alert instead of logging to console.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, my bad I didn't check the documentation properly.